# General Purpose Equality Checker

Tags: c#, equality

I'm maintaining a codebase and I've found two extension methods, dealing with checking the structural equality of objects, which I do not like at all (one invokes the other):

```
public static bool IsObjectEqual<T>(this T obj, T obj2)
{
    foreach (var pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var enumerable1 = pi.GetValue(obj, null) as IEnumerable;
        var enumerable2 = pi.GetValue(obj2, null) as IEnumerable;

        if (enumerable1 != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in enumerable1)
            {
                if (enumerable2 == null || !((object[])enumerable2).Contains(item))
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
        else if (!IsPropertyInfoValueEqual(pi, obj, obj2))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static bool IsPropertyInfoValueEqual<T>(PropertyInfo pi, T obj, T obj2)
{
    var val = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
    var val2 = pi.GetValue(obj2, null);

    if (val != null && val2 != null)
    {
        return val.Equals(val2);
    }

    return (val == null && val2 == null);
}
```

The problem is, I'm having trouble coming up with a scenario where I think they will fail, or cause problems. I know it in my waters that they are wrong, I just can't put my finger on it.

I've always used `IEquateable<T>` when implementing equality checking, so the absence of any of the framework classes/Interfaces which deal with equality is one thing which invokes my spidey senses. I realise this method is trying to be a generalised, reflection-based approach, but it makes me nervous (as mentioned).

Can anyone see a legitimate problem with these methods?

**Edit**

Big legitimate problem with the methods. The cast to object[] results in an InvalidCastException.

Comment: This feels rather like a code review question.

Comment: It is, but noone goes to that site at all.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it should be posted here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks very much Bradley. Feel free to post your comment as an answer. I'm not worried about the downvotes. So long as people help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be others, but I see two main problems with this code:

1. Reflection is expensive. Really expensive. To use it on such a large scale for something as simple as equality checking is just a bad idea. The code doesn't even cache the object graph so its having to do the full reflection *every time*. Under fairly common scenarios I can see this method being a performance bottleneck.
2. If members are `IEnumerable`, the code won't work as expected. Everything else is compared with reflection, but the collections are compared using `Contains`. This will do simple reference equality (for reference types at least) and doesn't reuse the reflective method. This would likely lead to undesirable results for the users of this method.

Implementing `IEquatable` and friends is a much faster, and safer, approach. The implementer gets to explicitly decide how the comparison works, and you don't need any reflection.